# Independence of render and window systems with connection through window handle

Tags: c++, architecture

Let's say we have interface window_creator that responsible for creation of windows. For simplicity it looks like this:

```
struct window_creator
{
virtual ~window_creator(){}
handle create_window(size_t width, size_t height, bool fullscreen);
};
```

Also, we have interface for render system that is responsible for rendering in window created by window_creator. It has, for simplicity, following code:

```
struct render_system
{
virtual ~render_system(){}
void create(handle window_handle);
};
```

Also, we have 2 implementations for window_creator interface:

```
struct windows7_creator : public window_creator
{
handle create_window(size_t width, size_t height, bool fullscreen) override {
//calls CreateWindow and returns HWND
}
};

struct macos_creator : public window_creator
{
handle create_window(size_t width, size_t height, bool fullscreen) override {
//calls createWindow_ and returns WindowRef
}
};
```

And 2 implementations for render_system interface:

```
struct dx_render_system : public render_system
{
    void create(handle window_handle) override{
    //calls CreateDevice, etc...
    }
};

struct opengl_render_system : public render_system
{
    void create(handle window_handle) override{
    //calls gl... etc...
    }
};
```

Now on windows platform I can create dx or OpenGL renderer. And on MacOs I can create OpenGL renderer.
The question is: what type of handle should I create to support independence of window_creator and render_system interfaces?

In my current implementation I wrote typedef for handle:

```
typedef void* handle;
```

Is there any more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Call me foolish but wouldn't it be easier to decouple the rendering from the windowing? You're probably better off with `#ifdef` blocks based on platform and library allowing for various project builds which specify the appropriate `typedef` for handle as operating system is not something that can change at runtime ;-)

Comment: yes, but rendering depends on window handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this sort of thing is done with the following pattern:

```
#ifdef OS_IS_WINDOWS

    #include "WindowsHandle.h"

    typedef WindowsHandle NativeHandle;

#elif OS_IS_MAC

    #include "MacHandle.h"

    typedef MacHandle NativeHandle;

#elif OS_IS_FOO

    #include "FooHandle.h"

    typedef FooHandle NativeHandle;

#end
```

You do not need to do runtime dispatching of the different NativeHandles - and in fact without sacrificing type-safety it is nearly impossible to do - as the definition of the platform-specific handles is not available on every platform.

You already know statically at compile-time what operating system you are on, so you may as well take advantage of that.

Comment: I do this in my internal class window_context in opengl_render_system. :)

Comment: @innochenti: Qt is an excellent and extremely popular open source cross-platform GUI C++ library.  Grab the tar ball of that and take a look at the code to see how they do it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Almost all C code is also C++ code, including the above.

Comment: This is not **good** C++ code. It’s C code compiled with a C++ compiler and doesn’t take advantage of C++’ strengths.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The operating systems present C apis - we have no control over the existence of things such as opaque native handles.  That given the above is as tighter factorization as possible.  There is nothing stopping the author from then writing a window class that wraps NativeHandle as a private member, better reuse to have one such class than 3 of them as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t use handles at all. Handles (in this context) are a trick employed by non-OO languages to support classes.

But C++ supports classes. So use them.

```
class window {
    // …
    virtual ~window() = 0;
};

class windows_window : window { … };

class cocoa_window : window { … };
```

These classes are RAII objects managing the raw handle resources, and providing convenience interfaces to the appropriate windowing functions.

Comment: This isn't a good way.  On any given build - window will have only one sub-class.  What's the point of having a vtable and runtime dispatching with only a single subclass?  Better to have the single concrete window implementation instatiated statically at compile time.

Comment: @user1131467 I still think that this is a very good way. Yes, you *can* statically dispatch at compile time but you gain almost nothing from it – after all, performance doesn’t matter here (you’re never going to create tens of thousands of windows) and it’s an easy, robust solution which faciliates separation into different compilation units. Templates, here, would make this more difficult (but not impossible). Of course you can also use `#define`s here but once again you don’t really gain any advantage from that, and you confuse IDEs, making development harder.

Comment: This is potentially cleaner than using the pre-processor for everything but you would still need platform based include guards somewhere for headers and platform specific code that would otherwise generate compilation errors.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: (1) So performance does matter in my opinion, especially if this pattern is going to be replicated across all the cross-platform classes.  All you need is a 100 x 100 grid of buttons to have ten thousand ui handles.  (2) Every IDE I know of (Visual Studio, Eclipse, QT Creator) is preprocessor-directive-aware.

Comment: @user1131467 Performance does matter. But my code has no noticeable impact on performance. If you have a 100x100 grid of buttons – no matter what environment you’re using – you’re doing it wrong. Completely wrong. This is never efficient. Regarding your point 2, the last time I used preprocessor directive switches to implement logic, VS failed to provide correct IntelliSense, although it was nominally preprocessor directive aware. Granted, that was some time ago.

Comment: I don't understand how wrapping handles into classes can solve problem of passing handles to render system.

Comment: @innochenti You do not pass handles to the render system. The render system is never supposed to see the handles, they are an implementation detail of the window class. In fact, your design is backwards. The render system should actually also be subclasses for each operating system, but it shouldn’t “create” anything, it should take care just of the rendering, and should be provided by a system-specific factory method.